# Calculate $\int_\Omega (4x^2+\frac{16}{9} y^2+z^2) dx \ dy \ dz$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_\Omega (4x^2+\frac{16}{9} y^2+z^2) dx \ dy \ dz$$
$$\Omega=\Big\{ (x,y,z):\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}+\frac{z^2}{16}=1   \Big\}$$

I have some difficulties to transform the integral boundaries

I think about using cylindrical coordinates

Thanks

Comment: Elliptic cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: Your integral looks like a *volume* (3D) integral, but $\Omega$ is a (2D) *surface*. Is that correct, or did you mean $\le 1$ in the definition of $\Omega$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=2u$, $y=3v$, and $z=4w$, then assuming you meant the interior of the ellipsoid,
$$
\begin{align}
\Omega
&=\left\{(x,y,z):\frac{x^2}4+\frac{y^2}9+\frac{z^2}{16}\le1\right\}\\[6pt]
&=\left\{(u,v,w):u^2+v^2+w^2\le1\right\}
\end{align}
$$
and changing variables, then changing to polar coordinates, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega(4x^2+\frac{16}9y^2+z^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z
&=24\int_\Omega(16u^2+16v^2+16w^2)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}v\,\mathrm{d}w\\
&=384\int_0^1r^24\pi r^2\,\mathrm{d}r
\end{align}
$$